# Sort array of dictionary

Tags: swift, sorting

I need to sort an array of dictionaries in the following ways. The array contains dictionaries with the following format:

```
[{
  fecha = "09:54:51";
  "nombre_vendedor" = Rafaela;
  numero = 501;
  precio = 52;
  "punto_venta" = Base;
  tipo = Gold;
}
{
  fecha = "09:54:51";
  "nombre_vendedor" = Miguel;
  numero = 400;
  precio = 40;
  "punto_venta" = Base;
  tipo = Gold;
}]
```

All I have to sort by the "numero" key.

Anyone have any idea how to do this. I've been trying to sortedArrayUsingComparator method but I get no result.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sort method the following way:

```
myArray.sort { $0["numero"]! < $1["numero"]! }
```

Comment: use sortInPlace(_:) in Swift 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "numero", ascending: true)
var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` method, passing a closure which, given 2 array elements, determines which one comes first.

A safe way to achieve that is:

```
array.sort { (lhs, rhs) in
    if let n2 = rhs["numero"] as? Int {
        if let n1 = lhs["numero"] as? Int {
            return n1 < n2
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

As you may notice, I usually prefer to use safe code vs. unsafe - that's the reason why the code checks for existance of the `numero` key on both dictionaries.

The above implementation sorts the array in place, placing items not having the `numero` key at the end - if you want the opposite case, just switch the last 2 `return` statements